# How to Adjust border-bottom line dynamically where text coming from dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  name = $('#select :selected').val();
  //some code here 
});
```

```css
. bdr-txtline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="Name" class="bdr-txtline">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I having dropdown which is on page1.html when I select any option so dynaamically those data going on another page which is having border bottom line.dropdown having some option short 3 words and some having 7or8 words so according to those words bIwant border bottom line should adjust(increase or decrease.
How  to Adjust border-bottom line dynamically where text coming from dropdown ?Can we take range of width for border bottom line and work on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `display:inline-block` in `bdr-txtline`.

```css
.bdr-txtline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="Name" class="bdr-txtline">
      two words
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="Name" class="bdr-txtline">
      more than two words
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but is there any jquery way to dynamically create width for border bottom line

Comment: if there is problem in using `display:inline-block` then you can use `text-decoration:underline` in `bdr-txtline`